# How to place a Windows special folder in config file

Tags: c#, .net

In my c# application I have a custom config section to determine where to store and retrieve certain files. However the default location for these is in the c:\ProgramData directory and we access it by using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

How can I prepopulate that directory in my config file without having to write out the raw string? It could also be a different special folder in some cases as well.

Basically it is a configuration element that looks like:

```
<searchpath path="" priority="" isfullpath=""/>
```

Each one of those is a path to search for configuration profiles for a product however over the course of different versions that directory has been moved around, but for backwards compatibility I still need to search the older paths if I can't find them in the newer paths.

For example I have to search in the product install directory then the ProgramData directory now as our most recent version moved it into the current products install directory, but our older version was storing it in the ProgramData directory.

Comment: So you're saying you'd rather pull the value from the configuration file, but it's possible that it may be overriden (i.e. set by hand)?

Comment: Do you want to store different `SpecialFolder`s or also custom paths or combinations of `SpecialFolder` and a user-defined path?

Comment: Correct. Right now I just have them hardcoded in the class, but I am tired of having to go in and make a code change every time.

Comment: It can be both special folders and user defined paths.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off storing a list of folders in the config with an order to try them in, and then some logic to fallback and ask the user if the application can't find it? This way you only need to modify the config file if the location changes again, and the user can always say where they installed it if they moved the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
  //string folderKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Folder"];
  string folderKey = "%CommonApplicationData%\\Test";
  var regex = new Regex("([%][^%]+[%])");
  string folder = regex.Replace(folderKey, (match) => {
    // get rid of %%
    string value = match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2);
    var specialFolder = (Environment.SpecialFolder)Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), value, true);
    return Environment.GetFolderPath(specialFolder);
  });
```

You can use %% to specify special folder inside your path, or use the value as ordinary path.

Comment: Thanks this offered the most flexibility for me.

Comment: I would use this method, but instead of using a regex and parsing the enum I would just call [Enviorment.ExpandEnviornmentVariables(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) (you would use [`%PROGRAMDATA%`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) to get `SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`)

Comment: Nice! I like that. @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so one approach might be to add an `<appSettings>` section in your `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="programData" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

and then in the application, build a static class that's used to retrieve the path:

```
public static class ProgramData
{
    private static string _path;
    public static string Path
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_path)) { return _path; }

            // let's set it then
            _path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["programData"]))
            {
                _path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["programData"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you want the path, all you do is:

```
var path = ProgramData.Path
```

Now, if there is an attribute in there **and** it has a value, it will use that. Otherwise it will default to the `SpecialFolder`.

One more note, you'll need to add a reference to `System.Configuration`.